# Async/Await with throw statement ends in weird behavior

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a method:

```
public async Task TakeOrder(int orderId)
{
    var request = new Request() { OrderId = orderId, UserId = _myUserId };
    var result = await _service.Request<OrderRequest, OrderResponse>(request);

    if (!result.Body.Success) // guaranteed to be true
    {
        if (result.Body.Error != null)
        {
            throw result.Body.Error;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to take order"); // always gets hit
        }
    }
}
```

So whenever I step into it, the code runs fine until the first if statement, no matter that result.Body.Success is true, it jumps right after into throw new Exception("Failed to take order") statement. Any ideas?

P.S.

I am more interested in why this works in the described manner instead of my expected flow. I can make the code work the other way, for instance making it synchronous or removing throw statement and replacing it with `Console.WriteLine("error");`

Comment: Use a debugger? Check that your debugging symbols are in order, and the application is compiled correctly? Not really much we can help you with here. I can guess all day long about what might be causing this :) Also, `throw result.Body.Error` is generally a bad idea - if you need to rethrow an exception like this, you want to wrap it in another exception or use a different throw mechanism that doesn't kill your stack trace.

Comment: If you're seeing something impossible while debugging, 9 out of 10 times your debugging symbols are out of date. Clean and rebuild. If that doesn't fix it, your understanding of the code is still wrong in some way. One subtle way this can fail is if `result.Body.Success` can be modified in the background, so it's `false` one time and `true` the next. This can happen even between stepping in the debugger.

Comment: I can confirm racing condition or background tasks are not mutating that boolean value neither clean/rebuild helped. That is why it ended up here - desperation :(

Comment: The chance that you're simply doing something wrong is still greater than the chance that the compiler contains a serious bug, although the latter can of course never be truly excluded. Try `throw new Exception($"{result.Body.Success}")`. If that gives an exception with message `true`, you've really got something interesting and you could take a look with `ildasm` to compare working and non-working code for differences. If there are none, you've narrowed it down to the jitter, but diagnosing problems there is harder.

Comment: Could this be just a debugger bug? Is it possible it's showing you the wrong line, but otherwise the code is executing correctly?

Comment: Exactly, this was just a debugger bug... got me crazy!